# Braintree iOS SDK saying no known class method

Tags: ios, xcode, braintree

I m getting this error. Anyone?

```
-(void)clientToken{

NSURL *clientTokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tectutiveclients.com/projects/carboss/api/getToken"];

 NSMutableURLRequest *clientTokenRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:clientTokenURL];

[clientTokenRequest setValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

 [NSURLConnection
 sendAsynchronousRequest:clientTokenRequest
 queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
 completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
     // TODO: Handle errors in [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode] and connectionError
   clientToken = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

     // Initialize `Braintree` once per checkout session


       [Braintree setupWithClientToken:clientToken
       completion:^(Braintree *braintree, NSError *error) {
           UIViewController *dropin = [braintree dropInViewControllerWithDelegate:self];
           [self presentViewController:[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:dropin]
                              animated:YES
                            completion:nil];

       // No known class method for selector setupwithClientToken Error

       }];


     UIViewController *dropin = [self.braintree dropInViewControllerWithDelegate:self];
     [self presentViewController:[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:dropin]
                        animated:YES
                      completion:nil];
     }];
}
```

Comment: I don't see any `setupWithClientToken` method in their [repo](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios) indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have any more problems, please [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

This is an inaccuracy in the docs. Instead, please use `braintreeWithClientToken:`

Example:

```
NSString *clientToken = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data 
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Initialize `Braintree` once per checkout session
self.braintree = [Braintree braintreeWithClientToken:clientToken];
```

Thanks for pointing this out! The docs will be updated shortly.